# Google Play sign in button is not working [BUG]?

Tags: android, google-chrome, youtube, google-play, google-play-services

I recently opened youtube on an android device and when I opened it, I got an error message like this:
Get Google Play
Sign in the Google Play

When it tried to redirect me to the app there was a green button called "Sign In" and when I click on it nothing happens, I have been trying to find it for more than an hour, watched many youtube videos surf the reddit to find the solution but nothing works.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

It seems some cache issues with google play.Try this:

**Clear Data and Cache:**

Go to Settings and Manage apps and select Play Store and Play Services.

Tap on Clear data at the bottom of the screen and select Clear cache and then Clear all data.

For more details check link: https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-google-play-wont-let-me-sign-in-error/

Answer (score 0):

simply uninstall Google Play Services and install it again, this way works for me.